# Port Forwarding - Minecraft Server

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, minecraft

I have a Minecraft server on my laptop that I want accessible online. 
I'm certain I've done all the steps correctly.

In server properties, I have set the ip address to be my computers IPV4 address;
192.168.2.50 (Static)
The generic Minecraft port is 25565.

I use the Bell Home Hub 3000 router.

Advanced DMZ is enabled, allowing my laptop to use the modem's WAN IP address as its own. It also puts my laptop outside the modem's firewall.

Port forwarding on my laptop with its IPV4 address at the port 25565 is already set up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uifEj.png

I've already tried completely disabling all firewalls.

I cannot contact my ISP to help me with this situation.

Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of trying to figure out a solution and hours of searching on google for answers, I've finally found my answer.

In the past, I've tried disabling all firewalls and checked online if the port was open with the server running. For some reason, the port would still be closed.

After looking over port forwarding settings and making sure everything was correct, I tried disabling all firewalls again and this time the port was open and everything worked.

After that, I went to "Firewall & network protection" > allow and app... > Change Settings > Allow another app... > Browse

Then, I opened the server. Opened task manager and navigated to the process, expanded the process and right clicked "Java(TM) Platform SE binary (32 bit)", and clicked on "Open file location". From there, it was simple. I just copy and pasted the path and allowed the app on my firewall. I turned all firewalls back on and now everything is working!